# Android: unable to instantiate C2DMBaseReceiver

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I directly copied all three C2DM classes into my project from Google Code's ChomeToPhone extension ([http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/.../c2dm](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/#svn/branches/page-initiated/android/c2dm/com/google/android/c2dm)), and then modified my Manifest per the instructions on the [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest) page. When I run my program, I get the following error. I can't figure out what's going on or why:

```
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.name.asdf.C2DMBaseReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.name.asdf.C2DMBaseReceiver
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.name.asdf.C2DMBaseReceiver
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)
06-12 18:50:43.243: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(923):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C2DMBaseReceiver` is an abstract class, you can't instantiate it. You should subclass `C2DMBaseReceiver` and provide your own implementation. Then register that class in your manifest. Note that you should put that class in the root of your package.

Answer (score 1):

C2DMBaseReceiver is abstract class:
public abstract class C2DMBaseReceiver extends IntentService{...}

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.